# Looping through nested nodes with XSLT, without specifying attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm having some trouble transforming some XML. I have a pretty generic template, and everything is coming in above a certain level. When I get to the first instance of nested objects, my transformer doesn't give me any output.

Here's what the XML looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Statistics>
  <IcServer name="Apsep00840">
    <ININ.Workgroup>
      <ININ.People.WorkgroupStats_Workgroup name="Campaign 1">
        <ININ.Workgroup_NumberAvailableForACDInteractions>11</ININ.Workgroup_NumberAvailableForACDInteractions>
        <ININ.Workgroup_LongestAvailable>00:09:21</ININ.Workgroup_LongestAvailable>
        <ININ.Workgroup_OnInboundACDInteractions>0</ININ.Workgroup_OnInboundACDInteractions>
        <ININ.Workgroup_OnInboundACW>0</ININ.Workgroup_OnInboundACW>
        <ININ.Workgroup_LongestInboundACDInteraction>N/A</ININ.Workgroup_LongestInboundACDInteraction>
        <ININ.Workgroup_InteractionsWaiting>42</ININ.Workgroup_InteractionsWaiting>
        <ININ.Workgroup_LongestWaitTime>00:00:42</ININ.Workgroup_LongestWaitTime>
        <ININ.Workgroup_LongestOnHoldTime>N/A</ININ.Workgroup_LongestOnHoldTime>
        <ININ.Workgroup_AgentsLoggedInAndActivated>79</ININ.Workgroup_AgentsLoggedInAndActivated>
        <ININ.Queue_Interval name="CurrentShift">
          <ININ.Workgroup_InteractionsEntered>9602</ININ.Workgroup_InteractionsEntered>
          <ININ.Workgroup_InteractionsAnswered>9578</ININ.Workgroup_InteractionsAnswered>
          <ININ.Workgroup_InteractionsAbandoned>25</ININ.Workgroup_InteractionsAbandoned>
          <ININ.Workgroup_AverageWaitTime>00:00:01</ININ.Workgroup_AverageWaitTime>
          <ININ.Workgroup_AverageHoldTime>00:00:01</ININ.Workgroup_AverageHoldTime>
          <ININ.Workgroup_AverageTalkTime>00:02:17</ININ.Workgroup_AverageTalkTime>
          <ININ.Workgroup_ServiceLevelTarget>N/A</ININ.Workgroup_ServiceLevelTarget>
          <ININ.Workgroup_AbandonedRateTarget>N/A</ININ.Workgroup_AbandonedRateTarget>
        </ININ.Queue_Interval>
      </ININ.People.WorkgroupStats_Workgroup>
      <ININ.People.WorkgroupStats_Workgroup name="Campaign 2">
        <ININ.Workgroup_NumberAvailableForACDInteractions>11</ININ.Workgroup_NumberAvailableForACDInteractions>
        <ININ.Workgroup_LongestAvailable>00:09:21</ININ.Workgroup_LongestAvailable>
        <ININ.Workgroup_OnInboundACDInteractions>0</ININ.Workgroup_OnInboundACDInteractions>
        <ININ.Workgroup_OnInboundACW>0</ININ.Workgroup_OnInboundACW>
        <ININ.Workgroup_LongestInboundACDInteraction>N/A</ININ.Workgroup_LongestInboundACDInteraction>
        <ININ.Workgroup_InteractionsWaiting>0</ININ.Workgroup_InteractionsWaiting>
        <ININ.Workgroup_LongestWaitTime>N/A</ININ.Workgroup_LongestWaitTime>
        <ININ.Workgroup_LongestOnHoldTime>N/A</ININ.Workgroup_LongestOnHoldTime>
        <ININ.Workgroup_AgentsLoggedInAndActivated>79</ININ.Workgroup_AgentsLoggedInAndActivated>
        <ININ.Queue_Interval name="CurrentShift">
          <ININ.Workgroup_InteractionsEntered>5171</ININ.Workgroup_InteractionsEntered>
          <ININ.Workgroup_InteractionsAnswered>5161</ININ.Workgroup_InteractionsAnswered>
          <ININ.Workgroup_InteractionsAbandoned>10</ININ.Workgroup_InteractionsAbandoned>
          <ININ.Workgroup_AverageWaitTime>00:00:01</ININ.Workgroup_AverageWaitTime>
          <ININ.Workgroup_AverageHoldTime>00:00:01</ININ.Workgroup_AverageHoldTime>
          <ININ.Workgroup_AverageTalkTime>00:02:28</ININ.Workgroup_AverageTalkTime>
          <ININ.Workgroup_ServiceLevelTarget>N/A</ININ.Workgroup_ServiceLevelTarget>
          <ININ.Workgroup_AbandonedRateTarget>N/A</ININ.Workgroup_AbandonedRateTarget>
        </ININ.Queue_Interval>
```

I'm basically trying to just load these results into a simple Bootstrapped table. My XSL for that table looks like this:

```xml
<table class="table table-hover table-dark table-striped">
<!-- Colspan for separating header --> 
    <col>
    <colgroup span="2"></colgroup>
    <colgroup span="2"></colgroup>
    </col>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: left">Workgroup</th>
            <th style="text-align: center" class="border" colspan="9">Workgroup Stats</th>
            <th style="text-align: center" class="border" colspan="9">Queue Stats</th>
        </tr>
        <span>
            <th class="border-left" scope="col">Available for ACD Interactions</th>
            <th scope="col">Longest Available</th>
            <th scope="col">On Inbound ACD Interactions</th>
            <th scope="col">On Inbound ACW</th>
            <th scope="col">Longest Inbound ACD Interaction</th>
            <th scope="col">Interactions Waiting</th>
            <th scope="col">Longest Interaction Waiting</th>
            <th scope="col">Longest Hold Time</th>
            <th class="border-right" scope="col">Logged on and Activated</th>
            <th scope="col">Intrs Received </th>
            <th scope="col">Intrs Answered</th>
            <th scope="col">Intrs Abandoned</th>
            <th scope="col">Avg Wait</th>
            <th scope="col">Avg Hold</th>
            <th scope="col">Avg Talk</th>
            <th scope="col">Svc Lvl Tgt</th>
            <th class="border-right" scope="col">Abandon Tgt</th>
        </span>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="border-bottom">
        <xsl:for-each select="IcServer/ININ.Workgroup/ININ.People.WorkgroupStats_Workgroup">   
            <tr class="border-bottom">
                <td style="text-align: left">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                </td>
                <td class="border-left">
                    <xsl:value-of select="ININ.Workgroup_NumberAvailableForACDInteractions"/>
                </td>
                <div style="text-align: right">
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ININ.Workgroup_LongestAvailable"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ININ.Workgroup_OnInboundACDInteractions"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ININ.Workgroup_OnInboundACW"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ININ.Workgroup_LongestInboundACDInteraction"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ININ.Workgroup_InteractionsWaiting"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ININ.Workgroup_LongestWaitTime"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ININ.Workgroup_LongestOnHoldTime"/>
                </td>
                <td class="border-right">
                    <xsl:value-of select="ININ.Workgroup_AgentsLoggedInAndActivated"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="//ININ.Workgroup_InteractionsEntered"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="//ININ.Workgroup_InteractionsAnswered"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="//ININ.Workgroup_InteractionsAbandoned"/>
                </td>
                <td class="border-right">
                    <xsl:value-of select="//ININ.Workgroup_AverageWaitTime"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="//ININ.Workgroup_AverageHoldTime"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="//ININ.Workgroup_AverageTalkTime"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="//ININ.Workgroup_ServiceLevelTarget"/>
                </td>
                <td class="border-right">
                    <xsl:value-of select="//ININ.Workgroup_AbandonedRateTarget"/>
                </td>
                </div>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Sorry for the dense lines. Basically what I'm experiencing here is all the regular nodes at the '''ININ.Workgroup''' level are showing up, but when I try to access the material in '''ININ.Queue_Interval''' node, they come back incorrcectly (N/A or 0 where there should be values). I've tried to put in the Attribute of **@CurrentShift** in the XPATH, like `<xsl:value-of select="ININ.Queue_Interval/@Name=CurrentShift/ININ.Workgroup_InteractionsEntered"/>` but it still comes in as all 0s and N/As.

In the full XML, there are 30 or so more **ININ.People.WorkgroupStats_Workgroup** nodes, so I'm trying to do this within one big loop that hits both the content at the Workgroup Level and then at the Queue_Interval level, but I'm not sure if that's the best way to go about it.

I've also tried some abridged XPATH, i.e.

```xml
<xsl:value-of select="./ININ.Workgroup_InteractionsWaiting" />
```

But again I'm just having a hard time narrowing down the problem. Thanks for your insight (and patience)!

Here's the transformed XML(HTML?) and the incorrect values:

[image]

I feel like it might be just looping the first value it finds, but not certain.

Comment: It is not clear what you have as output (mainly the so called "blank values") and what your expected output is. Please clarify.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the interest. I cleaned up the post a bit, and added my output. Initially when trying to use a discrete XPATH instead of the "//" that you see above, I was literally getting blanks in the table's td tags. I'm trying to get the values of `<ININ.Queue_Interval name="CurrentShift">` to populate in the table.

I've since gotten further, but I think there's something wrong with the way I'm looping, because now every value is coming back as 0 or NA, when I wouild expect a value of 9602 from ININ.Workgroup_InteractionsEntered, for Campaign 1, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to verify your code, because it's incomplete (and too long - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Assuming that your instruction:

```
<xsl:for-each select="IcServer/ININ.Workgroup/ININ.People.WorkgroupStats_Workgroup">
```

works, the correct expression to get a value from within the `ININ.Queue_Interval` section would be:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ININ.Queue_Interval/ININ.Workgroup_InteractionsEntered"/>
```

This is assuming there is only one such section within the current `ININ.People.WorkgroupStats_Workgroup`. If there can be more, and you want to specify the one you want by its `name` attribute, then use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ININ.Queue_Interval[@name='CurrentShift']/ININ.Workgroup_InteractionsEntered"/>
```

---

Here's a demo using a minimal example like the one you should have used:
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/naZXVEH

If you're getting a different result, then there's something wrong with your processing chain.

Comment: Thank you for the expression, I think I was forming that incorrectly. There are multiple sections of the ININ.Queue_Interval with the attribute  'name="CurrentShift"', so I wasn't sure if I could omit it in a loop.

The demo is immensely helpful, I will edit mine down to match, I wasn't sure how best to capture that I was iterating through two different levels, and I definitely went overboard.

Comment: If there can be multiple `ININ.Queue_Interval` sections with the attribute 'name="CurrentShift"' within the same `ININ.People.WorkgroupStats_Workgroup` parent, then how would you know which one to select?

Comment: Sorry, I keep making this more confusing. There's only one ```ININ.Queue_Interval``` section per ```ININ.People.WorkgroupStats_Workgroup``` parent node. Before I edited the question, my original selector was ```xsl:value-of select="ININ.Queue_Interval/ININ.Workgroup_InteractionsEntered"``` but my elements were coming back straight up blank, so that's where my main confusion came from. and so I started adding unnecessary predicates and just totally confused myself. The XSLT fiddle is going to change everything though, I was using online transformers to test : [